# Calling MATLAB from python does not release terminal

Tags: python, matlab

This is a strange error. I am calling matlab from python and it works but after it exits, the terminal no longer works, i.e. if I press enter, my prompt [user@server cwd]$ just keeps repeating and if I press other keys, nothing shows up. Is Matlab somehow not exiting gracefully? The pid for matlab no longer exists.

```
from subprocess import call

matlab_bin = '/volume/matlab/bin/matlabR2011b'

call([matlab_bin, '-nojvm', '-nodisplay', '-nosplash', '-r "ver; exit"'])
```

Comment: I tried exactly this and it worked just fine. Could be your matlab version, I'm on 2015a. Maybe try to add a ; after your exit call, matlab is weird.

Comment: Extra ; didn't help. It does seem to be a 2011b thing though, 2015b works just fine.